# Using Google Cartographer library standalone

Tags: ros, slam, localization, mapping, lidar

I am working on a project that requires the analysis of the results of different SLAM libraries with respect their accuracy on building a map. Right now, I am more interested in the development with these libraries, and one of the requirements is to NOT using ROS (we have our own framework)

So far, I have implemented the code using Karto, and my next step is implementing it with Google Cartographer, so I first looked for the docs, tutorials or examples of using standalone Cartographer library without success.. Hence, here I am: do you know or can share a minimum project or guide to use Cartographer library?

I have "translated" the ROS node, and reached a point in which I have a (not) working example: it creates an almost empty map :'(. I am using Odometry and Lidar data to fill in the trajectory, and the result is a map with some sparse gray pixels (I am using a PGM writer).

[image: This is the result of running cartographer]

My code is more or less like the following

```
float resolution = 0.05;

mapping::ProbabilityGridRangeDataInserter2D range_data_inserter(range_data_inserter_options);
auto grid_map = io::CreateProbabilityGrid(resolution, &conversion_tables);
auto map_builder = mapping::CreateMapBuilder(opts_map_builder);

SensorId odom_sensor;
odom_sensor.type = TrajectoryBuilderInterface::SensorId::SensorType::ODOMETRY;
odom_sensor.id = "odom";

SensorId lidar_sensor;
lidar_sensor.type = TrajectoryBuilderInterface::SensorId::SensorType::RANGE;
lidar_sensor.id = "lidar";

auto trajectory_id = map_builder->AddTrajectoryBuilder({odom_sensor, lidar_sensor}, opts_trajectory, &LocalSLAMResultCb);

auto trajectory_builder = map_builder->GetTrajectoryBuilder(trajectory_id);

sub_odom.registerCallback(&OnOdometryMessage);
sub_lidar.registerCallback(&OnLidarMessage);

....

map_builder->FinishTrajectory(trajectory_id);
map_builder->pose_graph()->RunFinalOptimization();
```

The callbacks for the odometry and lidar are the following:

- odometry:

```
sensor::OdometryData data{FromProtoTimestamp(odom.stamp()),
                                  transform::ToRigid3(protoOdom.odometry_data().pose())};
trajectory_builder->AddSensorData(odom_sensor.id, data);
```

- lidar:

```
sensor::TimedPointCloud ranges;
auto points_batch = ::absl::make_unique<io::PointsBatch>();

for (const auto &point : lidar.cloud()) {
   sensor::TimedRangefinderPoint p;
   p.position << cosf(point.angle()) * point.distance(), sinf(point.angle()) * point.distance(), 0.0f;
   p.time = 0.0f;
   points_batch->points.push_back({p.position});
   ranges.push_back(std::move(p));
}

sensor::TimedPointCloudData point_cloud{
   FromProtoTimestamp(lidar.stamp()),
   {lidar.pose().x(), lidar.pose().y(), 0},
   ranges
};

trajectory_builder->AddSensorData(sensor.id, point_cloud);
points_batch->origin << lidar.pose().x(), lidar.pose().y(), 0;

range_data_inserter->Insert({points_batch->origin, sensor::PointCloud(points_batch->points), {}}, grid);
```

I feel that I am missing a transformation, or the data I am providing is not well transformed.

When I use Karto, the result is something like this:
[image]

Hope you can help me, or if you know or can share some examples would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so to whoever wants to know or has a similar issue, the problem was, indeed, related to the transformation between the global frame and the point cloud frame.

The lidar message I have contains only distance and angle, without intensities. So, when I create a `TimedRangefinderPoint` I transform the distance and angle into a point in the world reference frame. Hence:

```
p.position << odom_x + cosf(point.angle()) * point.distance(), odom_y + sinf(point.angle()) * point.distance(), 0.0f;
```

being `odom_x` and `odom_y` the odometry estimation in x and y.

I will clean a bit the code, and I will post some kind of minimum tutorial to make this library to work.

**Edit**
Not a tutorial, but an example of usage of the standalone library: https://github.com/adiego73/cartographer If you think there are things wrong or can be changed for a better code, let me know! :)